# Shadow Image distortion for Custom Underline Spinner

Tags: android, layout, datepicker, android-spinner

Facing problem with higher version phones and tabs.

Foe lower versions the spinner are correct but for higher version (lollipop), showing below issues:

[image]

Comment: you have to assign your text size in dimen folder

Comment: Issue is not with the text size, it is with the rectangle shadow coming above the underline spinner.

Comment: can you attach your xml?

Comment: There is no xml as such, the underline spinner is made programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by stateListAnimator for lollipop version as

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```